# Very slow directory reads when there is lots of files

Tags: windows-7, directory-listing

On several Windows 7 boxes I'm having trouble with very large files. On my external hard drive I have a 2.2 GB Executable (extractor) as well as a 2.3 GB 7z file. However when ever I want to go to the folder I have to wait about 3 minutes before I can run the executable. During this time my hard drive activity light is going crazy, while I see little processor or RAM activity.

I can replicate this on multiple Windows 7 boxes ranging from Dual core Pentium E5300's with 2 GB RAM to a box with Dual Core Xeon Processors, 4 GB RAM, and RAID 0 HD's. It doesn't even make a difference when I use the internal HD instead of an external. This also happens when viewing a directory with a large amount of high resolution pictures.  In all cases the HD activity light is going crazy, while explorer is either unresponsive or the program I'm running won't open.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i experience a similar situation. I have a 1TB drive with many files of various sizes and types in many folders and sub-folders. If i do not use the drive for a while then when i access it or save to it the active window will hang for 10 seconds or so. i always assumed that since the drive is in-frequently used that windows was putting it into a low power state and that the delay was just the time it took for the drive to "wake up". perhaps it is something else though

Comment: See also for slow folder browsing: http://superuser.com/questions/442743/explorer-exe-hogging-cpu-folders-unresponsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're running into an antivirus scan. If it detects it as a compressed file, it might actually be scanning the contents every time you access it. Try exclude the file from your scanner settings and see if that helps.

Comment: Will try, although the Pentium E5300 computer is a company computer and uses Mcafee Enterprise, so I can't exclude it there unfortunately. I will test though on the other machine.

Comment: It's an interesting problem, so I'll keep an eye on this question.